# awk : parse and write to another file

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, xml

I have records in XML file like below.  I need to search for `<keyword>SEARCH</keyword>` and if present
then I need to take the entire record and write to another file.(starting from `<record>` to `</record>`)

Below is my awk code which is inside loop. `$1` holds line by line value of each record.

```
if(index($1,"SEARCH")>0)
{
print $1>> "output.txt"
}
```

This logic has two problems,

1. It is writing to `output.txt` file, only `<keyword>SEARCH</keyword>` element and not the whole record(starting from `<record>` to `</record>`)
2. SEARCH can also be present in `<detail>` tag. This code will even write that tag to `output.txt`

XML File:

```
<record category="xyz">
<person ssn="" e-i="E">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>SEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</record>
<record category="abc">
<person ssn="" e-i="F">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>DONTSEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is not present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</record>
```

Comment: Is that exactly your XML? Because it's not valid.

Comment: Please consider it just as a template. I would have posted it in hurry..

Comment: OK. I shall fix it for testing, and assume your XML is ok.

Comment: Yeah sure..Pls assume my XML is fine..

Comment: Does this have to be `awk`? It really isn't the best tool for this sort of thing.

Comment: As long as I get desired output, I can replace awk with whatever works fine..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you've posted is a sample, because it isn't valid XML. If this assumption isn't valid, my answer doesn't hold... but if that is the case, you really need to hit the person who gave you the XML with a rolled up copy of the XML spec, and demand they 'fix it'.

But really - `awk` and regular expressions are not the right tool for the job. An XML parser is. And with a parser, it's absurdly simple to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

#parse your file - this will error if it's invalid. 
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'your_xml' );
#set output format. Optional. 
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');

#iterate all the 'record' nodes off the root. 
foreach my $record ( $twig -> get_xpath ( './record' ) ) {
   #if - beneath this record - we have a node anywhere (that's what // means)
   #with a tag of 'keyword' and content of 'SEARCH' 
   #print the whole record. 
   if ( $record -> get_xpath ( './/keyword[string()="SEARCH"]' ) ) {
       $record -> print;
   }
}
```

`xpath` is quite a lot like regular expressions - in some ways - but it's more like a directory path. That means it's context aware, and can handle XML structures.

In the above: `./` means 'below current node' so:

```
$twig -> get_xpath ( './record' )
```

Means any 'top level' `<record>` tags.

But `.//` means "at any level, below current node" so it'll do it recursively.

```
$twig -> get_xpath ( './/search' )
```

Would get any `<search>` nodes at any level.

And the square brackets denote a condition - that's either a function (e.g. `text()` to get the text of the node) or you can use an attribute. e.g. `//category[@name]` would find any category with a name attribute, and `//category[@name="xyz"]` would filter those further.

XML used for testing:

```
<XML>
<record category="xyz">
<person ssn="" e-i="E">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<details>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
</names>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>SEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</person>
</record>
<record category="abc">
<person ssn="" e-i="F">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<details>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
</names>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>DONTSEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is not present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</person>
</record>
</XML>
```

Output:

```
 <record category="xyz">
    <person
        e-i="E"
        ssn="">
      <title xsi:nil="true" />
      <position xsi:nil="true" />
      <details>
        <names>
          <first_name/>
          <last_name></last_name>
        </names>
        <aliases>
          <alias>CDP</alias>
        </aliases>
        <keywords>
          <keyword xsi:nil="true" />
          <keyword>SEARCH</keyword>
        </keywords>
        <external_sources>
          <uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
          <detail>SEARCH is present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
        </external_sources>
      </details>
    </person>
  </record>
```

Note - the above just prints the record to STDOUT. That's actually... in my opinion, not such a great idea. Not least because - it doesn't print the XML structure, and so it isn't actually 'valid' XML if you've more than one record (there's no "root" node).

So I would instead - to accomplish exactly what you're asking:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ('your_file.xml'); 
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');

foreach my $record ( $twig -> get_xpath ( './record' ) ) {
   if ( not $record -> findnodes ( './/keyword[string()="SEARCH"]' ) ) {
       $record -> delete;
   }
}

open ( my $output, '>', "output.txt" ) or die $!;
print {$output} $twig -> sprint;
close ( $output );
```

This instead - inverts the logic, and deletes (from the parsed data structure in memory) the records you *don't* want, and prints the whole new structure (including XML headers) to a new file called "output.txt".

Comment: Thaks for your fast response. In which format do I need to save the file with the code you pasted? Can I invoke that file within unix shell script?

Comment: It's `perl`, you should be able to just run it.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, this might be a solution in awk!:

```
/^<record/ {
    x1="";
    while (match($0, "record>$")==0)
    {
        x1=x1 $0"\n";
        getline;
    }
    x1=x1 $0;
    if (x1 ~ />SEARCH</)
    {
        print x1 > "output.txt";
    }
}
```

This will extract the blocks, record> to \record>, containing the key "SEARCH" within, to the output file.

Comment: I ll give a try for this as well now..Thanks..

Comment: It gives syntax error for `/^<record/` . What is `/^<record/` ?

Comment: /^<record/ It is to filter by lines beginning with "<record". It's like grep. Copy it and save it as .awk, checked before carriage returns. And run it like this: awk -f script.awk file.xml

Comment: @user2488578 If not try it as one onliner  `awk '/^<record/ { x1=$0; while (match($0, "record>$")==0){ x1=x1 $0"\n";getline}x1=x1 $0"\n";if(x1 ~ />SEARCH</)print x1 > "output.txt"}' xml.txt`

Comment: Although, this does highlight one of the flaws with a regex approach - it's perfectly valid to indent XML. If someone does one day, then `/^<record/` will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that `awk`(same as and another text processors) is not a right xml-parsing tool:

```
awk '
    lines{
        lines=lines "\n" $0
    }
    /<\/record/{
        if(lines ~ /keyword>SEARCH</)
            print lines
        lines=""
    }
    /<record/{
        lines=$0
    }
    ' <input.txt >output.txt
```

Same as `sed`

```
sed -n '/<record/{:1;N;/<\/record/!b1;/keyword>SEARCH</p;}' <input.txt >output.txt
```